# CDK create new user in created user pool

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-cdk

I was trying to find ways to automatically create a few dummy users with CDK, like this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminCreateUser.html

but could not find anything useful

Is there any constructs or way we can achieve this?

Comment: https://github.com/awesome-cdk/cdk-userpool-user

Comment: this is helpful thank you so much!

Comment: I think you can use [`CfnUserPoolUser`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-cognito.CfnUserPoolUser.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is not always a construct class available for the part of a service you'd like to configure but there should be automatically generated `Cfn` prefixed resources which map 1:1 onto all available AWS CloudFormation resources and properties. As long as it's possible in CloudFormation it should be possible in the CDK.

If you look at the [`aws-cdk/aws-cognito` docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-cognito-readme.html) you'll notice two categories on the left hand menu `Constructs` and a little further down you will find `CloudFormation Resources`. One of those CloudFormation Resources is [`CfnUserPoolUser`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-cognito.CfnUserPoolUser.html) which should be what you are looking for.

If there is any issues utilizing the `Cfn` resources you can review options for [escape hatches](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/cfn_layer.html) to dig even deeper in to the `Cfn` constructs.